# TypeError when using useContext with GlobalContext in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror, react-context

I'm encountering a TypeError when trying to destructure properties from useContext(GlobalContext) in a React application. Here's the relevant code:
GlobalState.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import useSpeakerDataManager from './useSpeakerDataManager';

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const { isLoading, speakerList, toggleSpeakerFavorite } = useSpeakerDataManager();

    const provider = {
        isLoading,
        speakerList,
        toggleSpeakerFavorite,
    };

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={provider}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Speakers.js:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalState';

const Speakers = ({}) => {
    // ... (other code)

    const { isLoading, speakerList, toggleSpeakerFavorite } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    // ... (rest of the code)
};
```

[screenshot of Speakers.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slP4P.png)

> When I run `npm run dev` I get the following error:
> Server Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isLoading' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

[screenshot of the error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWLbw.png)

I've ensured that the GlobalProvider is wrapping the Speakers component and that the values are correctly provided. I've also confirmed that the useSpeakerDataManager function is returning the expected values.

- The GlobalContext is created in GlobalState.js and provided using GlobalProvider.
- I'm using the useContext hook in Speakers.js to access the values from GlobalContext.
- The useSpeakerDataManager function is used to populate the values in GlobalContext.
- The error occurs at this line: const { isLoading, speakerList, toggleSpeakerFavorite } = useContext(GlobalContext);

Comment: Pass initial state as an empty object `export const GlobalContext = React.createContext({});`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-m7hpwv?file=Gc.tsx